# AnyCpu и ссылка на разные библиотеки в атрибуте DllImport

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

Может ли проект с архитектурой AnyCpu брать разные библиотеки в зависимости от размера указателя? Т.е. что-то вроде такого:

```
internal class SdlFunctions
{
    private const string DllNameX64 = "x64\\sdl2.dll";
    private const string DllNameX86 = "x86\\sdl2.dll";

    #region SDL_video.h

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the number of video drivers compiled into SDL.
    /// </summary>
    [DllImport(DllNameX86, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    internal static extern int SDL_GetNumVideoDrivers();

    [DllImport(Is64Bit ? DllNameX86 : DllNameX64, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    internal static extern IntPtr SDL_CreateWindow();

    #endregion

    private static bool Is64Bit => IntPtr.Size != 4;
}
```

Но так сделать не выйдет, т.к. в атрибут `DllImport` нужно передавать константу.

Есть ли что-то другое кроме как использование `(Load\Free)Library`?

Comment: Есть ещё вариант с #if/#else. Либо таскать обе либы с exe и перед каждым вызовом функции проверять разрядность, чтобы вызвать соответствующую. Есть ещё 3й вариант - с аоп, но я не думаю, что в вашем случае он стоит свеч

Comment: @Александр: Я же написал AnyCpu, т.е. подразумевается что библиотека будет работать на любой платформе, а значит будет носить с собой обе версии разрядностей.

Comment: значит вариант с #if/#else отпадает. Остаётся все, что после

Comment: [Вот тут посмотри](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852634/using-a-32bit-or-64bit-dll-in-c-sharp-dllimport). Английский не нужен - всё в коде есть. Там два первых ответа интересуют: 1) Прописывать две функции за раз, например, `SDL_CreateWindow_32` и `SDL_CreateWindow_64`, а в коде уже проверять разрядность и вызывать нужную. Ошибки не будет, потому что библиотека подгружается при вызове 2) При инициализации класса, где хранятся эти функции, динамически подгружать нужную библиотеку. Функции из неё будут уже подхватываться автоматом - более элегантный способ и ваш случай под неё подходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если конфигурация именно такая, как вы описали: неуправляемые модули для разных архитектур имеют одинаковое имя и расположены в разных подкаталогах каталога с программой, можно использовать функцию [SetDllDirectory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setdlldirectoryw). При запуске приложения вызовите SetDllDirectory, передав каталог x86 или x64 в зависимости от текущей архитектуры. Объявление P/Invoke на каждую функцию оставить одно, содержащее только имя dll, без пути к подкаталогу. При запуске программа будет искать dll сначала в каталоге программы, затем в каталоге SetDllDirectory, и далее в системных каталогах, поэтому, чтобы все заработало, в каталоге программы dll с таким же именем быть не должно.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetDllDirectory(string lpPathName);

static void InitializeDll(){

    string path = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath;
    string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
    string subdir;

    if(Environment.Is64BitProcess) subdir = Path.Combine(dir,"x64");
    else subdir = Path.Combine(dir,"x86");

    SetDllDirectory(subdir);
}
```

Но, более логичное и независимое от WinAPI решение - иметь два объявления P/Invoke на каждую функцию и метод, вызывающий нужный в зависимости от архитектуры.